# Export Excel Issue with Firefox browser

Tags: java, excel

I am exporting an excel file using poi jars in java. Its working well with IE but when executed in Firefox, the filename is not containing xls extension. Can you please help me out?

Comment: what are you doing with your response headers?  Can you give it a default filname.xls

Comment: Please find out the code snippet added to output the xls file:      out = response.getOutputStream();
response.reset();
String fileName = reportType + WebConstants.DOT_XLS;
response.setHeader(WebConstants.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,WebConstants.ATTACHMENT_FILENAME + fileName);
response.setContentType(WebConstants.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREM);
wb.write(out);
response.flushBuffer();
logger.debug("After writing the data into excel");
out.close();

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the applyHeaders method in

http://stripesx.googlecode.com/svn-history/r189/trunk/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/stripes/action/StreamingResolution.java